# how to make text to return always lowercase in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

I have an input where user can search a chip and return a matched chip when they pressed enter but I'm wondering how I can make the input to return always lower case after enter is pressed since some time it look like a user can create two different chips, one with upercase and one with lowercase even though it will store only  in lowercase.

For example right now,

User enter "CHART" with upper case  -> it create "CHART" chip -> after browser is refresh, it show in lowercase "chart"

User enter "chart" with lowercase-> it create "chart" chip -> after browser is refresh, it show in lowercase "chart"

Also if a user create chip with uppercase first, it seem like they can create the same chip multiple time but if they create with lowercase first the input stop the user from creating the same chip multiple time and that is what I want.

**TRYING TO DO**

I just want to create only one chip if the user enter either with lowercase or uppercase and prevent if they try to create the same chips again either with uppercase or lowercase.

HTML

```
<input matInput #input [(ngModel)]="tagIn" (ngModelChange)="tagIn = $event.toLowerCase()" [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event,null)">
</div>
```

This is exactly look like my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-occkra
but also have the same problem, user can create multiple tags with the same word like "Apple" 'APPLE" "ApPLe" instead of just one.

Comment: You should first determine how your chip should be named i.e. lowercase, titlecase or uppercase. Now having determined how it should be named, you can convert it to the case you want before creating the chip.

Comment: I just want the chip to be named always with lowercase even if a user typed with Uppercase. for example, even if a user type "CHART"  and pressed enter, it will still show up in lowercase.

Comment: I just think this might be a solution to prevent a user from creating like "CHART", "chart", "ChART', CHarT", "CharT"..etc

Comment: just use javascripts string.toLowerCase() function in your submit function

Comment: I tried value.toLowerCase; and I can't create duplicated tags for the same chip anymore but I still able to create  all this "CHART", "chart", "ChART', CHarT", "CharT"...any suggestion

Comment: You can use a directive as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561412/2358409, simply use `toLowerCase()` instead of `toUpperCase()`

Comment: why not simple in `add function` add `event.value=event.value.toLowerCase()`. I don't check it but must be work

Comment: @Eliseo, I tried but still not working... still able to create  "CHART", "chart", "ChART', CHarT", "CharT" :(

Comment: @uminder  Please can you check this out...this is what my project look like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-occkra and also for this it able to create "Apple" "APPLE" "apPPLe" instead of just one

Comment: @Eliseo Please can you check this out...this is what my project look like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-occkra and also for this it able to create "Apple" "APPLE" "apPPLe" instead of just one

Comment: @AaseZi, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try using Lowercase Pipe in the HTML file.

https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe

```
{{ value | lowercase }}
```

Comment: Still not working... since I'm displying the chip on my input I'm not really sure where to placed that one. in the example, it placed inside <p> tag and not input  :(...

Comment: Please can you check this out...this is what my project look like https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdxrokeqakb and also for this it able to create "Apple" "APPLE" "apPPLe" instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code and the comments

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
           const input = event.input;
           const value = event.value.toLowerCase(); //<--first to lowerCase

            // Better use findIndex
           const index=this.allFruits.findIndex((f) => f.toLowerCase() ===value)
           if (index>=0) { 
             this.fruits.push(this.allFruits[index]); //<--push the element of
                                                      // allFruits, not the "value"
             this.allFruits.splice(index,1)  //remove the fruit of the list
           }  

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the lowercase pipe solved the issue. I just ran the project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdxrokeqakb)   and it works fine for me.

```
    <mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{ fruit | lowercase }}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
    />
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{ fruit | lowercase }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```