# How to trigger a ngModel on a native element?

Tags: angular

I have a directive that filters text pasted into an input field. Special characters are removed and only alphanumerical chars are kept.

```js
export class PasteFilterDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  handlePaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const rawText = event.clipboardData?.getData('text/plain');
    const parsedText = this.removeSpecialChars(rawText);

    this.element.nativeElement.value = parsedText;
  }

  private removeSpecialChars(str: string): string {
    return str.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]/g).join('');
  }
}
```

The directive works fine, except for the fact that after pasting, NgModel is not updated. In other words - the input value changes, but if I have an ngModel binding against that input field, it won't change. Here's a [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-5qpcpf.stackblitz.io) demonstrating the issue.

How can I write to the input field in a way that updates ngModel?

Comment: you can dispatch "input" event on a control to cause ngModel handle it, or you could inject NgControl and call its function directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attribute directive with ngModel to change field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106350/attribute-directive-with-ngmodel-to-change-field-value)

Comment: Injecting NgControl and calling `ngControl.control.setValue()` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an

`@Output('valueChange') valueChange = new EventEmitter<any>()`

after every

`this.element.nativeElement.value = parsedText;`

something like this

`this.valueChange.emit(parsedText);`

you can catch this from component template, for example:

`<... (valueChange)="updateModel($event)" ...>`

and finally implement your own update model logic in component

`updateModel(value: any) { /* Your Code */ }`.